# asp.net GridView, show multiple columns in multiple rows inside a single column

Tags: asp.net, gridview, datagrid

suppose there are 8 columns in a asp.net gridView. col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6,....I would like them to arrange in this way :

```
-----------------------------
col_one | col_two | col_three
-----------------------------
col1     col4      col6  
col2     col5      col7
col3          

-----------------------------
```

How could I do that ?

I googled and found an article [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16777/Merging-DataGrid-header-columns) which arranges several columns inside a column but does not put the arranged columns in different rows.

And what code could I post here.. I am just searching the way ...

How to achieve that ?

Should I switch to datagrid and why ?

Answer (score 0):

You should use `TemplateField` and then set templates for specific mode if required, like this:

```
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" DataKeyNames="Id" DataSourceID="ObjectDataSource1" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="col_one">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("col1") %>'></asp:Label><br />
                    <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("col2") %>'></asp:Label><br />
                    <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("col3") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="col_two">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("col4") %>'></asp:Label><br />
                    <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("col5") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="col_three">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("col6") %>'></asp:Label><br />
                    <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("col7") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
    <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ObjectDataSource1" runat="server" SelectMethod="GetItems" TypeName="WebTester.DataGridTester">
    </asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

And page code:

```
    public static DataTable GetItems()
    { 
        //generate some demo data...
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("Id",typeof(int));
        dt.Columns.Add("col1", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("col2", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("col3", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("col4", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("col5", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("col6", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("col7", typeof(string));
        dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {1,"some","data","in","first","row", ".", ".." });
        dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 2, "second", "record", "inside", "demo", "datatable", "-", "--" });
        return dt;
    }
```

Comment: this is the error I got : `System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataGridColumnCollection must have items of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataGridColumn'. 'asp:TemplateField' is of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.TemplateField'.`

Comment: I have prepared you a complete working sample. First add new page called "DataGridTester.aspx" to your project and paste code above.